# Multiply pandas column values with the column header value (if the header value is number/digit)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have updated with the real dataset for the columns after loading csv into pandas dataframe. Thanks.
My csv data has many columns and some of the columns are as below. I have to multiply each column value if the column header is a digit or number.

Input data: FOr example 5th and 7th columns have digits on the header. I need to multiply all the values in that column by that respective header value. Thanks

```
Unnamed: 0 Unnamed: 1 Retailer Unnamed: 2 1,750.00  Unnamed: 7  1,800.00
Name       Toy        N1       Manager    0.8       city        10
Name       Toy        N2       Manager    20        city        30
Name       Toy        N1       Manager    1.1       city        10
Name       Bas        N1       Manager    0.2       city        10
```

Expected output:

```
Unnamed: 0 Unnamed: 1 Retailer Unnamed: 2 1,750.00     Unnamed: 7  1,800.00
Name       Toy        N1       Manager    1400         city        18000
Name       Toy        N2       Manager    35000        city        54000
Name       Toy        N1       Manager    1925         city        36000
Name       Bas        N1       Manager    350          city        36000
```

Please let me know as I have many columns like 5th and 7th column in my dataset. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the isdigit function to check if the column is a digit and if yes multiply it to the column otherwise keep the column as is.

```
(
    df.apply(lambda x: x.mul(float(str(x.name).replace(',','')))
             if str(x.name).replace(',','').replace('.','',1).isdigit() 
             else x)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the columns and if it is a number you can multiply the rows by that column.

```
for col in df.columns:
    if col.isdigit():
        df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x * pd.to_numeric(col))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#extract columns that start with numbers
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.match('^\d+')]

#assign result of multiplication back to origina dataframe
df.loc[:,cols] = df.loc[:,cols].mul(cols.str.replace(',','').astype(float))

df


  Unnamed: 0    Unnamed: 1  Retailer    Unnamed: 2  1,750.00    Unnamed: 7  1,800.00
0   Name        Toy          N1        Manager      1400.0      city     18000.0
1   Name        Toy          N2        Manager      35000.0     city     54000.0
2   Name        Toy          N1        Manager      1925.0      city     18000.0
3   Name        Bas          N1        Manager      350.0       city     18000.0
```

Comment: Thanks. It works with an example dataset as above. But in my real dataset from csv, the 5th and 7th columns are like "1,750.00   1,800.00" respectively. In this case, these are not picked up as number_cols. I tried changing format in csv also to numbers. But it's not working. Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: ```"1,750.00 1,800.00" ``` two numbers in one column header? u mind updating ur data with this info? it also allows other ppl to jump in

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and I have updated the dataset. Apologies.

Comment: i made some edits. kindly check if it works on ur actual data

Comment: Thanks. I checked and "number_cols" is not filtering the digits column..

Comment: let's test this : ```df.filter(regex=r'^\d+[,]*')``` what do u get?

Comment: I get only  the first column (index) 0 1 2 3 column

Comment: select_dtypes('number') also selects only the 1st column.

Comment: that's not right, select_dtypes selects numeric columns. we are talking about ur original dataframe right? cos unnamed: 0 is the first column there and that is all text, so select_dtypes cant pick that

Comment: Also there are Nan in those two columns which requires transaformation. Hence dtype shows as "Object" for those two columns.

Comment: ohhh, ok. might have to take a different approach then. gimme a min

Comment: made an update to the code. i assume if the column starts with a number, then it's a number entirely. let's see what it gives. also test the outcome of ```df.columns[df.columns.str.match('^\d+')]``` does it give u the numbers columns?

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind guidance. I am struck again as in the real dataset there are some duplicate numbers (1,800.00.1)  in the headers or the fist line of my csv file. This is throwing error with your current solution. I will solve that trouble first and try your option again. Thanks

Comment: I renamed the columns and hence "df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.').str[0]" and hence I could proceed with your proposed solution.    "cols = df1.columns[df1.columns.str.match('^\d+')]"   gives the output as below.

Comment: Index(['1,750', '1,800', '1,800'], dtype='object')

Comment: so it works fine. for some, but leaves out the 1,800.00.1. which doesnt make sense cos numbers have just one dot in them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212314/discussion-between-sammywemmy-and-lilly).